# Unable to locate element and the 'By' class while using Selenium with NUnit

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, nunit

I am trying to run a *Selenium IDE* generated script with *NUnit* using Visual Studio. But encountering an error:

> Cannot open file: 'C:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs'
>   Error- 'File does not exist.
>
> File- C:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs'

and

> Cannot open file: 'C:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\By.cs'
>
> Error- 'File does not exist. 
>   File- C:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\By.cs'

I tried *Xpath* also instead of *Name/Id*, but the error still persisted.
I don't have an idea as to why is it looking for these files there when I have neither *NUnit* nor *Selenium* directory there.

Code:

```
[Test]
public void TheForSeleniumAssignmentTest()
{
    string baseURL = "http://www.cakespot.in";
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();        
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/");
    Thread.Sleep(8000);
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(text(),'More Pictures')])[2]")).Click();
    Thread.Sleep(8000);            
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("name")).SendKeys("pooja");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("phone")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("phone")).SendKeys("123456");            
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("date"))).SelectByText("14");
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("month"))).SelectByText("5");
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("time"))).SelectByText("8:30");
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("day"))).SelectByText("pm");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("button")).Click();
}
```

Comment: Have you added both NUnit and Selenium as references for your project? Without them your project is not going to work.

Comment: Yeah. I have added 'nunit.framework' reference for NUnit and 'Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium, ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core, WebDriver and WebDriver.Support' for Selenium.

Comment: it doesn't appear that way, unfortunately.  your IDE should be correcting you, and telling you that you need to create `using` statements for the respective classes you are using.. If it isn't, then the appropriate libraries are most likely not referenced in your project.

Comment: @sircapslot I have only pasted the code here which is being problematic, keeping in mind the forum ethics. The library and reference part is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For your By.cs file issue go to this [page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/By.cs?r=f6d1dfcfcdbd32f982e7ee874a64e2e30cbf8d40), there you'll find the By.cs file just save it as a cs file using Notepad or similar software(make sure it's a .cs file and not just a .txt).

Now when you get the same issue you should find a browse to the file link in the window when the error occurs. just browse to your saved file (by the way if you can't find it via visual studio it means you didn't save it as a .cs file).

alternatively you could download the whole .zip file and then browse to the wanted .cs file.

Well It's looking for the file because you tried to step into the line that cause the exception.

Comment: by the way just google RemoteWebDriver.cs and you'll find it's .cs file too.